# Many-to-Many Relationship GAE NDB Need Parent or Child?

Tags: google-app-engine, many-to-many, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to read and replicate the code for many-to-many relationships found in https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling. One thing that I've noticed is that **group** and **user** does not seem be each other's parent or child, or it does not say so.

My problem involves an entity of company and an entity of user. I would think naturally that a company may or may not belong to a user, and a user also may or may not belong to a company.

So, the question is: in many-to-many relationship, **does one entity need to be a parent or child of another** entity? Does this matter?

I think I just need verification telling me that, "Yes" neither are parent or child of each other, and "yes" you need to follow the database system theory, but not the relational model. Just a list of each entities like a JsonProperty containing each entity of each other, or something like that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parent-child relationship is used to establish entity groups, which are needed in transactions. They have nothing to do with normal (one-to-many or many-to-many) relationships between entities.

No, parent-child relationship is not necessary to establish entity relationships.

Yes, to establish "relationship" between entities you just need to store a Key (or ID) of one entity into another entity. I'm putting "relationship" in quotations as this is really just a link to another Entity, not a relationship managed by database (such as relationships in SQL databases).